# How to secure firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been building my app via firebase and things are going pretty well. Recently I was prompted to add security rules to my real time database. Although I understand what to do, I noticed that there is no rules tab for my authentication section for firebase. Are there any steps I should take to secure my authentication information, besides password management. Manipulating users' data would be bad but deleting my authentication and thus who all has made an account would be catastrophic.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules ?

Comment: Authentication is already secured. You can turn on it or off, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the [projects members](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/overview#members) of your Firebase Project, with the corresponding rights, can access the Authentication console of your Project.

An [end user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users) of your Firebase Project, i.e. a user declared in the Authentication service, can only interact with **his own account** through the Client SDKs, e.g. [modify his password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password) or [update other properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) of his own profile.